# Glossy or transparent glass reflection not achieved due to reflection from environment

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine, glass

I decreased the roughness and increased the transmission of a simple cube to get a transparent glass like image but the Environment texture is being reflected in the object..
[image: This is what I want][image: This is what happens[![][2[![]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlY1A.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlY1A.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjPva.png)
[[image]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcCtg.png)

Comment: Could it be that you're using eevee? [This is a decent tutorial to get a similar effect using eevee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0Rjj9HwSiA&ab_channel=BlenderPirate)

Comment: Yes im using evee

Comment: But Even if I am using cycles the World Environment gets reflected